# Warning on -webkit-filter: when setting background

Tags: html, css

I get this warning on CSS3 when I set the background of my div:

```
 -webkit-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00f2f2f2', endColorstr='#f2f2f2', GradientType=0);
```

It says,

> is not a valid value for `-webkit-filter`.

Comment: you're using a ms value for a -webkit- prefix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following **filter** wlil **only** be read **by IE**:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#000000');
```

[image]

For **chrome** you should be using

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ccc), to(#000));
```

[image]

**For FireFox**

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ccc,  #000);
```

[image]

## [Cross-Browser CSS Gradient](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient)

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I think the reason was that i used resharper to  create vendor compliant gradient code for me.

Answer (score 1):

[Cross-browser gradient generator](http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)
Also you could upload image and zilla automatically generate valid gradient and cross-browser code.